# Installing and registering shell extension Context menu From wix installer

Tags: c#, installation, wix, contextmenu, shell-extensions

I created sharp shell extension for customizing right click  menu context  of windows using .Net. The result of the project is a .dll. I tries to install and register it using Server manager Tool which exists with the sharp shell tools and it worked successfully. Now I need to install and register this shell extension from my wix project, as I need the user to install my app and get his right click context menu of windows customized after installation.

I need detailed steps as I am new in using Wix installer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and visit our [help]. Your question lacks details to determine where you are stuck in your current attempt. If you didn't start yet then I'm afraid we can't help you as we are not very well suited for providing complete tutorials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you can register your extension from wix:

First you need to define (in the product scope) custom actions to register/unregister your extension:

```
<Product>
    <!-- ... -->
    <CustomAction Id="InstallShell" FileKey="srm.exe" ExeCommand='install "[INSTALLFOLDER]\MyExtension.dll" -codebase' Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
    <CustomAction Id="UninstallShell" FileKey="srm.exe" ExeCommand='uninstall "[INSTALLFOLDER]\MyExtension.dll"' Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />
</Product>
```

Then you need to customize the install execute sequence to launch these custom actions:

```
<Product>
    <!-- ... -->
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="InstallShell" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
        <Custom Action="UninstallShell" Before="RemoveFiles">(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
</Product>
```

"MyExtension.dll" is the id of your extension dll ressource in your wix project:

```
<Component Guid="*">
    <File Id="MyExtension.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="bin\$(var.Configuration)\MyExtension.dll" />
</Component>
```

Same for srm.exe:

```
<Component Guid="*">
    <File Id="srm.exe" Source="packages\SharpShellTools.2.2.0.0\lib\srm.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

You need to retrieve srm.exe associated to the version of Sharpshell you use (i recommend you to use the nuget package). You can find information on this here :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/653780/NET-Shell-Extensions-Deploying-SharpShell-Servers

Hope it will help you ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed Help  @rene

Comment: Instead of `[INSTALLFOLDER]` I had to use `[INSTALLDIR]`